# Как сохранить, а потом воспроизвести действия пользователя в GUI

Tags: java, события, отладка, трассировка

Есть java-приложение (портабельное - Windows, Linux, iOS), в котором есть весьма насыщенный и развитый GUI. Множество окон, карточных компоновщиков, на них - кнопки, слайдеры, комбобоксы текстовые поля и много чего еще, на что пользователь может тыкать мышью и в чем нажимать разные кнопки клавиатуры. На многих окнах есть панели с векторной и растровой графикой, в которых отрабатываются практически все события мыши для разных хитрых манипуляций с визуализируемыми данными.

Все это в виде здоровенного jar-а отдаётся заказчику. Но, иногда пользователь говорит мне, что после определенной последовательности действий какие-то из элементов интерфейса ведут себя неправильно. А что именно делал, ни он, ни я воспроизвести не можем. Чтобы поймать ошибку, мне надо знать точную последовательность его манипуляций мышью и клавиатурой в GUI и воспроизвести все это под отладчиком (пользую eclipse). Сейчас пишу максимально много в логи, но довольно муторно потом их читать и пробовать повторить действия. А с движениями мыши это совсем невозможно.

ВОПРОС. Есть ли какие-нибудь средства (с минимальными изменениями в коде) чтобы на стороне пользователя записать в файл его действия, а потом на моей стороне чтобы воспроизводились те же действия, и остановка отладчика на контрольной точке не убивала процесс?

Comment: А почему вам просто при падении программы не локить exeption  и писать в лог стектрейс падения? Так будет понятно весь порядок вызова функций приведший к ошибке

Comment: @Mira идея логичная (и весьма хорошая), но дело в том, что у автора может не возникать никакого исключения, а просто в коде *логическая* ошибка. Код где-то написан не так, как надо. Вот только где?

Comment: @Зонтик логи автора не устраивают - читать и воспроизводить "довольно муторно". Есть только одна волшебная кнопка записи в файл без логов - видео с экрана писать. И то это не гарантирует воспроизведение ошибки на стороне программиста. Есть же еще данные, и особенности компьютера-системы пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне не причина возникновения исключения нужна. Его, действительно, может и не быть. Мне нужна вся последовательность действий, за весь сеанс, чтобы воспроизвести ситуацию, например, когда какой-нибудь комбобокс остался неактивным. А мест и условий активации и деактивации элементов интерфейса - десятки.